# Android studio : Required type Fragment, provided : FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, xml

So basically, I'm trying to do a Task manager on Android Studio with some additionnal features.
I began the project by doing a drawer menu which led me to do some fragment.
I am now doing the Task managing part, following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27MXFSWC1_4&list=PLzEWSvaHx_Z2MeyGNQeUCEktmnJBp8136&index=3&ab_channel=PenguinCoders

However, I have a slight problem using the ToDoAdapter :

```
public Todoadapter(TaskFragment activity){
activity.getActivity() = activity;}
```

Using this function I am doing a :

```
taskadapter = new Todoadapter(this);
```

And I getting an error that says :

```
unexpected type activity.getActivity() = activity;
required : variable
found : value
```

How could I resolve this issue ?

I tried changing the function with some different things, but that led me to basically nothing

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to create a constructor for a tool adapter like this

```
activity = activity.getActivity();
```

you were trying to assign the activity to the value.